# Nativescript Tests with Appium won't run for iOS

Tags: nativescript, appium, appium-ios, nativescript-vue

## Problem E2E Tests for NativeScript Vue will not run on iOS

I'm trying to run E2E tests for NativeScript Vue on the iOS platform however I'm running into following problem:

The tests fail with following message:

```
  1) sample scenario
       "before all" hook:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'statBarHeight' of undefined
      at Function.<anonymous> (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/lib/appium-driver.js:260:37)
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/nativescript-dev-appium/lib/appium-driver.js:4:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)

  2) sample scenario
       "after all" hook:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'quit' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (e2e/sample.e2e-spec.js:14:22)
      at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
      at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:130:23)
```

Running the script with following command produces following error:

**Command:**

npm run e2e -- --runType sim.iPhone11Pro --verbose

**Error:**

```
    [debug] [WebDriverAgent] *** Cloning YYCache

    [debug] [WebDriverAgent] Failed to check out repository into /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/Carthage/Checkouts/RoutingHTTPServer: Could not create working directory (Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "You don’t have permission to save the file “RoutingHTTPServer” in the folder “Checkouts”." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/node_modules/appium-webdriveragent/Carthage/Checkouts/RoutingHTTPServer, NSUnderlyingError=0x7faab903f5d0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"}})

Session info:
undefined
Appium settings:
 > CALL settings()
 > GET /session/appium/settings
[HTTP] <-- POST /wd/hub/session 500 54845 ms - 269
[HTTP]

[HTTP] --> GET /wd/hub/session/appium/settings

[HTTP] {}

[debug] [HTTP] No route found. Setting content type to 'text/plain'
```

(I've omitted the correct looking parts, only written the errors)

### Any chance this could be my fault?

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same error

Comment: @florianbezagu unfortunately no :/

Comment: @Thomas Did you ever figure this out? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @RoderNY sadly no. I came to the conclusion that I will ditch NativeScript whenever I can. It is causing way too many problems and this is just the lesser of the problems.